# Images displayed are as a gallery, but don't want to

Tags: html, css, image, slideshow, blogs

I made this blog for travel and photography, which is one of my main hobbies.
I got a free template and made all the necessary changes all by myself, crediting the author of it of course. But I'm having this issue...

Posts on the main page, that have more than 1 photography, will appear as a slide gallery, in which I don't want that, because it will mess up the layout when photos are vertical.

As you can see here: http://jcruz-foto.blogspot.pt/search?updated-max=2016-10-29T18%3A30%3A00%2B01%3A00&max-results=7

Post nº 6 where it says "Campeonato Regional MX Ribatejo 2016"...

This is the code associated with the slider. Removing it won't do the trick lol...

```
<style type='text/css'>
/**
 * BxSlider v4.1.2 - Fully loaded, responsive content slider
 * http://bxslider.com
 *
 * Written by: Steven Wanderski, 2014
 * http://stevenwanderski.com
 * (while drinking Belgian ales and listening to jazz)
 *
 * CEO and founder of bxCreative, LTD
 * http://bxcreative.com
 */


/** RESET AND LAYOUT
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto 60px;
    padding: 0;
    *zoom: 1;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;

}

/** THEME
===================================*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    background: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
        -ms-transform: translatez(0);
        -o-transform: translatez(0);
        transform: translatez(0);
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* LOADER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-loading {
    min-height: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}

/* PAGER */

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #666;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager .bx-pager-item,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-controls-auto-item {
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a {
    background: #666;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    outline: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active {
    background: #000;
}

/* DIRECTION CONTROLS (NEXT / PREV) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    left: 20px;
    background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-WCgfaNs6MAU/VBnoMBFzakI/AAAAAAAABxw/oqXkrdC99Kw/s1600/slider-arrows.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    right: 20px;
    background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-WCgfaNs6MAU/VBnoMBFzakI/AAAAAAAABxw/oqXkrdC99Kw/s1600/slider-arrows.png) no-repeat -30px 0;
}

/*.bx-controls-direction a {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.bx-wrapper:hover .bx-controls-direction a {
    opacity: 1;
}*/

.bx-wrapper .bx-next:hover, .bx-wrapper .bx-prev:hover {
    opacity:.7 !important;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    outline: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a.disabled {
    display: none;
}

/* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    text-align: center;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
    background-position: -86px 0;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    outline: 0;
    background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
    margin: 0 3px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
    background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto {
    right: 0;
    width: 35px;
}

/* IMAGE CAPTIONS */

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    padding:20px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-caption span {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

</style>
```

Also, I wanted to make smaller vertical images on the front page, but I just can't seem to do it as well... Vertical images are way too big

Comment: What result do you want? You want to remove the slider or automatically fix the height of vertical images?

Comment: Yes... I don't want a slider, at the main page i just want one image preview, and fix the vertical images height, they're too big

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are using a Blogspot theme and this functionality is integrated into the theme.

You can switch it off from the theme settings.

OR

If you just want to get rid of this functionality via CSS only, paste this code at the bottom of your stylesheet.

**Remember this is a HACK so your slider will not work anywhere else. Use this code ONLY if you want to get rid of slider functionality via CSS only and are unable to switch off the auto slider creation from theme settings.**

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a{display:none;}
ul.bxslider li{display:none !important;}
ul.bxslider li:first-child{display:block !important;}
```

Comment: I don't think I want that...
If I could put the slider inside the post, instead of outside it, that would be great

Comment: @JoãoCruz well you need to know how to edit the template in order to do that. I would suggest you reading about Blogspot Themes.

Comment: thanks, it seems its a bit impossible for me. I tried to contact the designer of it, and willing to buy the full version, but no answer

Comment: Question: While making a post on blogger, either I say that image should be small, medium or whatever, the template is forcing the image to be always that default size. I can't figure out the code that's causing it...

Comment: Well you have to dig deep into the template files.